# $\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}f\ast\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)=f(x)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, convolution

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a smooth measurable function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi(x)=0$ outside the ball centered at the origin with radius 1 and that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x)\,dx=1$. For $\varepsilon>0$, define $\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x):=\dfrac{\varphi(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})}{\varepsilon^n}$. Suppose $f\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, then \begin{equation}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}f\ast\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)=f(x),\end{equation} where \begin{equation}f\ast\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x-y)\varphi_{\varepsilon}(y)\,dy.\end{equation}

Does anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: this is a *very* standard exercise in functional analysis, which usually is a first semester, graduate analysis course. I just wanted to emphasize that the idea of using smooth-bump functions are gonna be very popular, as is demonstrated by the excellent answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|f\ast\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\int f(y)\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy-\int\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(x)dy\right|\\
&=\left|\int(f(y)-f(x))\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\left|\int(f(y)-f(x))\varphi((x-y)/\epsilon)dy\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\left|\int_{|x-y|<\epsilon}(f(y)-f(x))\varphi((x-y)/\epsilon)dy\right|\\
&\leq\dfrac{M}{\epsilon^{n}}\int_{|x-y|<\epsilon}|f(y)-f(x)|dy\\
&=\dfrac{Mv_{n}}{|B_{\epsilon}(x)|}\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}|f(y)-f(x)|dy\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For the first equality, did you rewrite $f(x)=\int\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(x)\,dy$? If so, why can you do that? Do we have $\int\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy=1$?

Comment: First of all we have $\displaystyle\int\varphi_{\epsilon}(y)dy=1$, and then change of variable $y\rightarrow x-y$.

Comment: Why do we have $\int\varphi(x)dx=\int\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)dx$? My text says by the change of variable, but could you please explain why?

Comment: That is change of variable $x\rightarrow x/\epsilon$ with Jacobian $1/\epsilon^{n}$.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much.